# To identify which CALayer clicked on should I subclass or this there a better way?

Tags: objective-c, ios, calayer

I have an array of CALayers which represent game pieces. I call hottest: to determine which game piece was touched and then move it around. How can I figure out which piece it was?

1. Subclass CALayer and add a property
2. Use the CALayer as key in NSMutableDictionary, value some additional data
3. Loop through my array and compare the pointers
4. Something more clever?

Comment: Turns out CALayer is a KVC complaint container. Meaning I can add properties to it with

    [theLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:50] forKey:@"someKey"];

and get they by

    someKeyValue=[theLayer valueForKey:@"someKey"];

This way I can add identifying information to the CALayers and not have to do anything fancy.

Comment: It won't let me answer it myself till later.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit test your view for CALayer, even when they are moving.

```
- (CALayer *)hitTest:(CGPoint)thePoint
```

This is a half related topic that you may be interested to look at :
[Core Animation, unexpected animated position and hitTest values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962335/core-animation-unexpected-animated-position-and-hittest-values)