# gesture to imageview is not working during animation in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

I am implementing animation of one imageView.In this animation my ballon image is going from bottom to top and I want to hide it if user will touch the balloon.But my gesture is not working during animation.Could anyone help me.Thanks in advance.

```
img=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
     img.frame=CGRectMake(150, 450, 50,50);
     [self.view addSubview:img];
     img.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ballon3.png"];
     img.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
tapGestureRecognizer.delegate=self;
[img addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:30];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];

CGAffineTransform scaleTrans =
    CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);

CGAffineTransform rotateTrans =
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle * M_PI / 180);
img.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(scaleTrans, rotateTrans);

img.center = CGPointMake(30,320);
```

this is the method for gesture.but this method is not calling.

```
-(void)handleTapFrom:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
  img.hidden = yes;  
}
```

Comment: Try NSLOg , if control is coming there or not

Comment: Does it work outside the animation? If not, try to check a few things: - Does your img is using a strong pointer?
- Does your viewcontroller implements the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use block for your animation so like it : (Note the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`, which is important)

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    // Your animation here
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // Once completed do stuff here;
}];
```

I let you set the other params like you want.

If you need to work prior to iOS 4.0, you will need to set your animation in a separate thread. [Check here for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937864/having-problems-allowing-interaction-in-uiview-animation)